# Как работает DELETE IGNORE...?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.
Вопрос по mysql. Как работает DELETE IGNORE...? Не пойму, какие ошибки игнорируются. Читал официальный стандарт, не понял.
Вот ссылка - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: Уточняю - Вы не можете понять, какие ошибки могут произойти при удалении элементов БД ?

Comment: я не понимаю, как эта фигня работает

Answer (score 2):

Если говорить простыми словами то `IGNORE` откидывает определенные типы ошибок и возвращает предупреждения вместо этого. При том если без `IGNORE` при возникновении ошибки работа останавливается, то при `IGNORE` - просто пропускается ошибка(но выводиться предупреждение) и прерывание не случается.
Игнорируемые ошибки:
`ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR` `ER_DUP_ENTRY` `ER_DUP_ENTRY_WITH_KEY_NAME` `ER_DUP_KEY` `ER_NO_PARTITION_FOR_GIVEN_VALUE` `ER_NO_PARTITION_FOR_GIVEN_VALUE_SILENT` `ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2` `ER_ROW_DOES_NOT_MATCH_GIVEN_PARTITION_SET` `ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED_2` `ER_SUBQUERY_NO_1_ROW` `ER_VIEW_CHECK_FAILED`

Comment: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR
ER_DUP_ENTRY
ER_DUP_ENTRY_WITH_KEY_NAME
ER_DUP_KEY
ER_NO_PARTITION_FOR_GIVEN_VALUE
ER_NO_PARTITION_FOR_GIVEN_VALUE_SILENT
ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2
ER_ROW_DOES_NOT_MATCH_GIVEN_PARTITION_SET
ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED_2
ER_SUBQUERY_NO_1_ROW
ER_VIEW_CHECK_FAILED

Comment: Вот все типы игнорируемых ошибок

Comment: спасибо. за ответ

Comment: Не за что, будут вопросы - обращайтесь

Comment: мне с другого форума еще ребята подсказали по этому вопросу. сейчас напишу

Comment: Vental, приведите, пожалуйста, пример, который показывает работу DELETE с IGNORE и без IGNORE. чтобы была видна разница

Comment: И так, к примеру у нас есть таблица из которой мы хотим удалить ячейки под индексом от 2 до 4, но у нас возникла любая из представленных ошибок на ячейке 3. _DELETE_ процесс закончится тут же выдав нам **EROR**, в тоже время как _DELETE IGNORE_ процесс выдаст нам **WARNING** и продолжит работу игнорируя эту ячейку